# While I'm able to update my mysql database to an int but I can't input a string

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-workbench

Edit => Problem resolve : 
I changed my query to this and now it's working thank you yall:

```
    query_update = ("UPDATE comments SET label = '%s' WHERE id = %s"%(new_label, id))
```

I'm working on a school project to update a mysql database thru a form in a flask app.

While I run my query updating a column to an integer it works, but when my query is a string it doesn't.

I only know a little about mysql and even less about mysql workench.

Thanking  in advance.

Here is my code :

```
cur_update = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

#working
query_update = ("UPDATE comments SET label = %s WHERE id = %s"%(1, id))
#working
query_update = ("UPDATE comments SET label = %s WHERE id = %s"%("1", id))
#not working
query_update = ("UPDATE comments SET label = %s WHERE id = %s"%("test", id))
#returing the following error
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test' 
in 'field list'

cur_update.execute(query_update)
cnx.commit()
cur_update.close()
cnx.close()
```

I tried several datatype for the concern column but every one of them return the same error.

Comment: You must not use string interpolation to form SQL commands.

Comment: You should pass your variables separately as query parameters instead of trying to glue them into your SQL. https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL queries generally require that strings be enclosed in single quotes.

Your UPDATE statement evaluates to this:

```
UPDATE comments SET label = test WHERE id = 1
```

Since `test` isn't in quotes, SQL expects it to be the name of a column.

Put quotes around the value and it will work:

```
query_update = ("UPDATE comments SET label = '%s' WHERE id = %s" % ("test", id))
```

Comment: seems we got a troll getting fun with proper answers.

Comment: `c.execute("UPDATE comments SET label = '%s' WHERE id = %s", ("test", id))` is much more recommended

Answer (score -2):

just quote it. string values must be quoted in SQL

```
query_update = ("UPDATE comments SET label = %s WHERE id = %s"%("'test'", id))
```

please notice the single quote before and after the value.

and by the way. doing it this way is insecure. use prepared statement with binding parameter.

Comment: well got -2 so long for answering such question.

Comment: "doing it this way is insecure. use prepared statement with binding parameter." ?

Comment: @PRMoureu improper handling of SQL query parameter can lead to SQL Injection security flaws, you can have a description here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection the principle of prepared statement can be found here too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: so why not suggesting this way rather than a simple string interpolation ?

Comment: @PRMoureu simple, the level of the question indicated that the person wasn't really aware or the security implications nor the 'usual' SQL API, so i wanted him to at least understand why it didn't work and didn't want to directly add security concern, lastly tying it on my phone was tedious, that's why i edited it when i had time on my desktop. anyway, case close as it seems to have worked for him :)